# Sharepoint 2010 with existing SQL Reporting Services

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

going through my list for things I need to prep for in my upcoming Sharepoint 2010 installation.

We'll be installing SP2010 Enterprise to make use of the BI components, with the web server on it's own VM.  We'll then use our existing SQL Server (2005) to host all SP databases.  Finally, we also have an existing SQL Analysis Services implementation (2008), of which we want to consume reports out of.

That being said, I can use help with any\all of the following:

- From what I can gather, we need the Sharepoint Reporting Services Add-In installed.. somewhere.  Where would that go?
- I've also seen *[older articles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff686706.aspx)* mention that the SQL Analysis Server will need a minimal SP installation to have the SP object model, but I'm not sure if this is still necessary.
- I'm also concerned that we already have the reporting services setup as a standalone installation, I don't want to screw up reporting for our data warehouse team (unless I have to) by setting up the reporting services for sharepoint.
- I have limited exposure to any BI\Reporting Services at this time, but this will definately be a key component for our SP rollout.  Links to any articles, blogs, papers, and\or good books would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have reporting services setup, you cannot use Reporting Service integrated mode (reference: http://ericniemiec.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-in-sharepoint-2010-integration-mode/)  The advantage here is you can manage RDL files similar to other document libraries in SharePoint.

Since you have SSRS setup in native mode, you can view reporting services reports for using a set of web parts that display a SSRS folder and all the reports in that folder, or run a set report, see: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9437